# Rails validation failure with has_many and create during database seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to seed my database but I get a failed validation. It can't find `user_id`:

```
Validation failed: Characters user can't be blank
```

Why is this happening? When you do `self.characters.create` isn't the user id automagically passed to the character that you're creating?

**user.rb**

```
has_many :characters
accepts_nested_attributes_for :characters

after_save do
  if (self.characters.count == 0)
    self.characters.create
  end
end
```

**character.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
validates :user_id, presence: true
```

**seeds.rb**

```
User.create!(email: "barrysmashpants@hotmail.com",
             activated_at: Time.zone.now,
             characters_attributes: [{ first_name: "Baz", last_name: "Chump" }])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error: you can't save a `Character` object in the database unless it has an associated parent `User` object.

In your db/seeds.rb file, you are trying to create `Character` objects, and then `User` object, but a `Character` object needs a valid `user_id`.

Solution:

You need to use `inverse_of` to tell explicitly Rails that `Character` objects dependant upon `User` object.

```
has_many :characters, inverse_of: :user
```

And in your `Character` model:

```
belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :characters
```

The validation in `Character` model should be like following:

```
validates :user, presence: true # It will server the same purpose as does `user_id`
```

## Edit:

The problem doesn't lie in `after_save`. The problem exists in the following line:

```
User.create!(email: "barrysmashpants@hotmail.com",
             activated_at: Time.zone.now,
             characters_attributes: [{ first_name: "Baz", last_name: "Chump" }])
```

Through this code, Rails will first create a `Character` object with the attributes: `{ first_name: "Baz", last_name: "Chump" }`, but since a `Character` object must have an associated `User` object, so Rails will fail to create a `Character` object, stating that `Characters user can't be blank`.

Putting `inverse_of` makes Rails create a `User` object first, and then using its `id`, create the subsequent `Character` objects.

Comment: I've made the change you suggested but I'm still getting the same error. Why is it trying to create the `Character` object first? I deliberately put `self.characters.create` in an `after_save` exactly because the `Character` object needs the user id.

Comment: @Bazley I have updated my answer. Apply the change in both models.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting the same error even after updating both user and character models.

Comment: @Bazley Make sure the validation in `Character` model is like this: `validates :user, presence: true`

Comment: You are a genius! It works, thank you. But I still don't understand - why is it trying to create the `Character` model first when I put `self.characters.create` in an `after_save`?

Comment: It isn't about `after_save`. The thing lies in your seeds.rb file. I have updated my answer, kindly check it.